# Find such collection of functions whose countable supremum is again that type of function but arbitrary supremum is not?

Tags: general-topology

There is one such example:

> Consider the uncountable non-discrete P-space $S$. In $S$, all points are isolated except for a distinguished point $s$, a neighbourhood (nbd.) of $s$ being any set containing $s$ whose complement is countable. The closed set $\{s\}$ is not regular $G_\delta$ subset (not even a $G_\delta$ subset), but $\{s\}$ is an uncountable intersection of its nbds. which are open and closed and hence are regular $G_\delta$-subsets.
>
> Let us consider a nbd. $G_a$ of $s$; $G_a$, being a clopen (open and closed) set, is a regular $G_\delta$-subset and hence $S\setminus G_a$ is a regular $F_\sigma$-subset. Let us define functions $f_a$ from $S$ to $\Bbb R$ by
>
> $$f_a(x)=\begin{cases}
> 1,&\text{if }x\in S\setminus G_a\\
> 0,&\text{if }x\in G_a\;.
> \end{cases}$$
>
> Here each $f_a$, being the characteristic function of a regular $F_\sigma$-subset, is RLSC (regular lower semicontinuous).
>   But arbitrary suprema of $f_a$ are not RLSC, although countable suprema of $f_a$ are RLSC.

So, guys, can you help me with another example of such functions whose countable supremum is again that type of function but arbitrary supremum is not?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Try using LaTeX, breaking up the wall of text, and clearly defining your topology.

Comment: You should also take care to define what you mean by "type of function," as the problem is trivial if you let that mean whatever I want it to mean.

Comment: The finite infimum and countable supremum of RLSC functions are RLSC. But the arbitrary supremum of RLSC functions may not be RLSC. I want another such example of functions. Otherwise you can help me, with example of collection of sets where the above property follows i.e. the collection is closed under finite infimum and countable supremum, but not closed under arbitrary supremum (except the collection of regular G delta subsets). Thank you.

Comment: A trivial example: take $X$ to be any uncountable set, and $\mathscr{F}$ the set of indicator functions of countable subsets of $X$. Another: the family of bounded functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brian. Can you elaborate these. It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of simple examples.

1. Let $X$ be an uncountable set, and let $\mathscr{C}$ be the family of countable subsets of $X$. For each $C\in\mathscr{C}$ let $\chi_C:X\to\{0,1\}$ be the [indicator (or characteristic) function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $C$. Let $\mathscr{F}=\{\chi_C:C\in\mathscr{C}\}$. For each $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{C}$ let $\mathscr{F}_{\mathscr{A}}=\{\chi_C:C\in\mathscr{A}\}$; it’s easy to check that $\sup\mathscr{F}_{\mathscr{A}}=\chi_{\bigcup\mathscr{A}}$. If $\mathscr{A}$ is countable, then $\bigcup\mathscr{A}\in\mathscr{C}$, and $\sup\mathscr{F}_{\mathscr{A}}\in\mathscr{F}$. If, however, $\mathscr{A}$ is uncountable, then it can happen that $\bigcup\mathscr{A}$ is also uncountable (e.g., if $\mathscr{A}=\big\{\{x\}:x\in Y\big\}$ for some uncountable $Y\subseteq X$), in which case $\sup\mathscr{F}_{\mathscr{A}}\notin\mathscr{F}$. Thus, $\mathscr{F}$ is closed under taking countable suprema but not under taking arbitrary suprema.
2. Let $\mathscr{F}$ be the set of bounded functions from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_1$, i.e., the set of $f:\omega_1\to\omega_1$ such that there is an $\alpha<\omega_1$ for which $f(\xi)\le\alpha$ for each $\xi\in\omega_1$. Suppose that $\mathscr{A}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ is countable. For each $f\in\mathscr{A}$ let $\alpha_f<\omega_1$ be such that $f(\xi)\le\alpha_f$ for each $\xi\in\omega_1$. Let $\alpha=\sup\{\alpha_f:f\in\mathscr{A}\}$; the supremum of a countable set of countable ordinals is a countable ordinal, so $\alpha<\omega_1$. Clearly $f(\xi)\le\alpha_f\le\alpha$ for each $f\in\mathscr{A}$ and $\xi\in\omega_1$, so $(\sup\mathscr{A})(\xi)\le\alpha$ for each $\xi\in\omega_1$, and hence $\sup\mathscr{A}\in\mathscr{F}$. On the other hand, if for $\eta\in\omega_1$ we set $f_\eta(\xi)=\eta$ for all $\xi\in\omega_1$, then $\{f_\eta:\eta\in\omega_1\}$ is an uncountable subset of $\mathscr{F}$ whose supremum is the function $f$ such that $f(\xi)=\omega_1$ for each $\xi\in\omega_1$, which isn’t even a function from $\omega_1$ to $\omega_1$, let alone a bounded one.

Comment: what ω stands for? And how we can set these bounded functions in fuzzy setting?

Comment: @Birojit: $\omega_1$ is the first uncountable [ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). I don’t know enough about the fuzzy setting to help there.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Brian for your co-operation.

Comment: @Birojit: You’re welcome.